# Discord embed not assigning roles on user eaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have mostly rebuilt the code and made changes.

When I do !embed everything works as it should, the bot creates the embed, and reacts with the emojis set, it just doesn't give user the roles once they react with the emojis the bot reacts to the post with..

I decided to add in some random print statements to hit the console per step and found I can see up to `while True` as commented in my code but after that the print statements don't respond.

My error handler/trace back has been pretty good so far and picked up everything, so its like after `while True` nothing exists, I believe the problem lies within this line:

```
reaction = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: user == reaction.message.id == msg.id)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
desc1 = ("React with the corresponding emoji to game specific channels you want\n"
         "\n - Counter Strike\n"
         " - Warframe\n"
         " - Lost Ark\n"
         " - Chiller\n"
         " - Warhammer")

@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx: commands.Context):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Create Your Profile", description=(desc1))
    embed.set_footer(text="Jammys Bot")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    print('it works here')
    while True:
        print('it works here 1') ## makes it up to here. Error handle/trace back isn't picking anything below up so its like its non-existent.
        reaction = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: user == reaction.message.id == msg.id) # stops working here
        print('it works here 2')
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            print('it works here 3')
            CSGO = ctx.guild.get_role(780182144747569193)
            print('it works here 4')
            await bot.add_roles(CSGO)
            print('it works here 5')
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            WF = ctx.guild.get_role(780244861130768395)
            await ctx.add_roles(WF)
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            LA = ctx.guild.get_role(947231964753170473)
            await bot.add_roles(LA)
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            CHILL = ctx.guild.get_role(896853904384458772)
            await bot.add_roles(CHILL)
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            WH = ctx.guild.get_role(896882687816630293)
            await bot.add_roles(WH)
```

Comment: Your code appears to be functioning. Are all the required intents (message content) enabled?

Comment: @EricJin yes that is correct, I have my intents basically set to all.

Comment: It does also have full admin rights, the bot can post in this specific channel as I have been testing with welcome/leave messages.

Comment: What's the actual behavior? When you run the command, is the embed ever sent? I see the code for adding the reactions and checking for them, so do either of those parts break?

Comment: @EricJin Not sure how i would run that specific command to be honest, I just close my python session and relaunch to see if it posts the embed once online but, nope it doesn't edited my post to reflect some changes I have done. Not sure how I can test them parts without the embed being posted. Cheers for all the help so far.

Comment: You have to actually run the command, which is different depending on your prefix. If you're using normal commands, you should have a prefix when you made your `commands.Bot`. Then do, for example if your prefix is `!` then `!takemysword`

Comment: @EricJin sorry, yeah I did realise I had to do that after awhile but I did go ahead and rework the code, as well add in some print statements to where I think things where working and then stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

To send it to a specific channel you can try this code

```
channel =client.get_channel(your channelid)
msg = await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: As you can see by your code, that is basically going to send a "hello" to a channel ID you set which is not what I am trying to achieve currently.

Comment: Sorry about that :(Just write 'embed =embed' instead of hello. Also channel id must be int

Comment: hey no worries, your still trying to help so don't be sorry. I did actually guess I would need to change hello to embed=embed, unfortunately still doesn't work though :( edited my post to reflect the changes I made...

Comment: Interesting.Did you copied your channel and used it as a parameter. Anyways i got this code from this website. Maybe it can help:https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel